# Chained ifelse() results in 'data.frame' values in cells

Tags: r, excel, list

So I created a column which uses conditional values in other columns using a chained ifelse() function that returns a "Low", "Medium" or "High". The values for this cell are displayed correctly when viewing the dataframe via the environment in R. However, if I try to export my dataframe to xlsx using openxlsx, I get the error:

```
write.xlsx(Data, file = "Analysis.xlsx") 

Error in is.nan(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Then, when I check the column data type using str(Data) I get the following output:

```
$ Financial    : chr  "Correct" "Correct" "Correct" "Correct" ...

$ Composite    : num  5 5 3.64 5.36 4 ...

$ Risk         :'data.frame':   30 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Appetite: chr  "High" "High" "High" "Low" ...
```

When I convert the Data$Risk column using...

```
Data <- as.character(Data$Risk)
```

...the column gets unreadable, with every cell consisting out of 30 observations.

Here is an example of the first two rows after the as.character manipulation:

```
[1] "c(\"High\", \"High\", \"High\", \"Low\", \"High\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"High\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"High\", \"High\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\")"
 [2] "c(\"High\", \"High\", \"High\", \"Low\", \"High\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Low\", \"High\", \"Low\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"High\", \"High\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\", \"Medium\")"
```

Before the as.character manipulation the row was viewable (first two row's as an example):

```
Data$Risk
   Appetite
1      High
2      High
```

using dput:

```
dput(Data$Risk)
structure(list(Appetite = c("High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
"Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", 
"Low", "High", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I make this column readable as.character, without making what is in it unreadable?

Comment: Since you appear to have an embedded frame, you might be able to "fix" it with `SurveyData$Risk <- SurveyData$Risk$Appetite` or similar (back up your data before doing that). If that doesn't work, it would be helpful to see the output from `dput(head(SurveyData))`, not just the console representation or the `str` output.

Comment: @r2evans I have put the output of dput in the OP. I have done something similar to your suggestion, however, how do I now delete the data.frame class in the data frame? I can't seem to delete it using Data <- Data[, ! names(Data) %in% Deleted.Columns, drop = F] with Deleted.Columns <- c("Data$Risk","Data$Risk$Appetite")

Comment: I suggested `dput(head(SurveyData))`, not `dput(SurveyData$Risk)`. They're different, I'm not confident how it is integrated in.

Comment: You should show us the code that created the bad object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the data looks something like this:

```r
xx <- structure(list(i = 1:30, Risk = structure(list(Appetite = c("High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "High", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
head(xx)
#   i Appetite
# 1 1     High
# 2 2     High
# 3 3     High
# 4 4      Low
# 5 5     High
# 6 6   Medium
str(xx)
# 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ i   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ Risk:'data.frame': 30 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ Appetite: chr  "High" "High" "High" "Low" ...
```

Notice how the normal representation of this on the R console is to show `Appetite` as the column name instead of `Risk`. I've always found this choice to be ... unintuitive. This behavior does change if there is more than one column in the embedded frame, at which point this name would *show* as `Risk.Appetite`

```r
# just for demo, a different variable
yy <- structure(list(i = 1:30, Risk = structure(list(z=1:30,Appetite = c("High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "High", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))

head(yy)
#   i Risk.z Risk.Appetite
# 1 1      1          High
# 2 2      2          High
# 3 3      3          High
# 4 4      4           Low
# 5 5      5          High
# 6 6      6        Medium

### counter-intuitive access
yy$Risk.Appetite
# NULL
yy$Risk$Appetite
#  [1] "High"   "High"   "High"   "Low"    "High"   "Medium" "Low"    "Medium" "Low"    "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Medium" "Low"    "Medium" "Low"    "High"   "Low"    "Medium" "Medium" "High"   "High"   "Medium"
# [28] "Medium" "Medium" "Medium"
```

Back to `xx`, with a single-column embedded frame. You can "fix" the column with:

```r
xx$Risk <- xx$Risk$Appetite
head(xx)
#   i   Risk
# 1 1   High
# 2 2   High
# 3 3   High
# 4 4    Low
# 5 5   High
# 6 6 Medium
str(xx)
# 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ i   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ Risk: chr  "High" "High" "High" "Low" ...
```

(Notice how the name changed from `Appetite` to `Risk`.)

Comment: Yes, just replacing the $Risk <- xx$Risk$Appetite fixed the issue for me! I don't know how this inception column within a column was created, but it is now fixed.

Comment: (I completely agree with [@user2554330's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109517/chained-ifelse-results-in-data-frame-values-in-cells/67111019?noredirect=1#comment118624595_67109517): to preclude this from bugging you again, it might be good to review the code that created this object. It might be a new question, certainly, but providing a fix for the *cause* is much better than for the *symptom* as here. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `$Appetite`

```
Data <- as.character(Data$Risk$Appetite)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. How does it come that you can have a column within a column? I do not know how I created it that way.

Comment: @M1ke You can try `dput(Data)` to see the data structure.